# Can I insert a dynamic number of rows into a table using values from the table?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I want to insert a dynamic number of rows into a table, based on information in that table.

I can do it using the code below, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the loop.

The commented out section was my best attempt at what I was trying to do, but it gave me an error of:
"The reference to column "iCount" is not allowed in an argument to a TOP, OFFSET, or FETCH clause. Only references to columns at an outer scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here."

```
DECLARE @TableX TABLE (
      TDate         DATE
    , TType         INT
    , Fruit         NVARCHAR(20)
    , Vegetable     NVARCHAR(20)
    , Meat          NVARCHAR(20)
    , Bread         NVARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT INTO @TableX VALUES
      ('2016-11-10',1,'Apple','Artichoke',NULL,NULL)
    , ('2016-11-10',1,'Banana','Beet',NULL,NULL)
    , ('2016-11-10',1,'Canteloupe','Cauliflower',NULL,NULL)
    , ('2016-11-10',1,'Durian','Daikon',NULL,NULL)
    , ('2016-11-10',2,NULL,NULL,'Rabbit','Rye')
    , ('2016-11-10',2,NULL,NULL,'Sausage','Sourdough')
    , ('2016-11-11',1,'Elderberry','Eggplant',NULL,NULL)
    , ('2016-11-11',2,NULL,NULL,'Turkey','Tortilla')
    , ('2016-11-11',2,NULL,NULL,'Venison','Vienna')

SELECT * FROM @TableX

DECLARE @BlankRow TABLE (
      ID            INT IDENTITY
    , TDate         DATE
    , TType         INT
    , iCount        INT
    )

DECLARE   @Counter1 INT = 0
        , @RowCount INT

; WITH BR1
    AS (
        SELECT TDate, TType, COUNT(*) AS iCount
            FROM @TableX
                WHERE TType = 1
                    GROUP BY TDate, TType
        )

, BR2
    AS (
        SELECT TDate, TType, COUNT(*) AS iCount
            FROM @TableX
                WHERE TType = 2
                    GROUP BY TDate, TType
        )

INSERT INTO @BlankRow
    SELECT ISNULL(BR1.TDate, BR2.TDate) AS TDate,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(BR1.iCount,0) < ISNULL(BR2.iCount,0) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS TType,
            ABS(ISNULL(BR1.iCount,0) - ISNULL(BR2.iCount,0)) AS iCount
                FROM BR1
                    FULL JOIN BR2
                        ON BR1.TDate = BR2.TDate

WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @BlankRow)
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        SET @RowCount = (SELECT iCount FROM @BlankRow WHERE ID = @Counter1)
            INSERT INTO @TableX
                SELECT TOP (@RowCount) tx.TDate, br.TType, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
                    FROM @TableX tx
                        LEFT JOIN @BlankRow br
                            ON tx.TDate = br.TDate
                        WHERE br.ID = @Counter1
    END

/*INSERT INTO @TableX
SELECT TOP (tx.iCount) tx.TDate, br.TType, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
        FROM @TableX tx
            JOIN @BlankRow br
                ON tx.TDate = br.TDate*/

SELECT *
    FROM @TableX
        ORDER BY TDate, TType,
        ISNULL(Fruit,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20)),
        ISNULL(Vegetable,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20)),
        ISNULL(Meat,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20)),
        ISNULL(Bread,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20))
```

The data is silly, I know, but my end goal is to have two different Tablix's in ReportBuilder that end up with the same number of rows so the headers of my groups show up at the same place on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
declare @TableX table(TDate     date
                     ,TType     int
                     ,Fruit     nvarchar(20)
                     ,Vegetable nvarchar(20)
                     ,Meat      nvarchar(20)
                     ,Bread     nvarchar(20)
                      );

insert into @TableX values
 ('2016-11-10',1,'Apple','Artichoke',NULL,NULL)
,('2016-11-10',1,'Banana','Beet',NULL,NULL)
,('2016-11-10',1,'Canteloupe','Cauliflower',NULL,NULL)
,('2016-11-10',1,'Durian','Daikon',NULL,NULL)
,('2016-11-10',2,NULL,NULL,'Rabbit','Rye')
,('2016-11-10',2,NULL,NULL,'Sausage','Sourdough')
,('2016-11-11',1,'Elderberry','Eggplant',NULL,NULL)
,('2016-11-11',2,NULL,NULL,'Turkey','Tortilla')
,('2016-11-11',2,NULL,NULL,'Venison','Vienna');


with DataRN as
(
    select *
            ,row_number() over (partition by TDate, TType order by TDate) rn
    from @TableX
)
,RowsRN as
(
    select tt.TDate
            ,tt.TType
            ,td.rn
    from (select distinct TDate, TType
            from @TableX
            ) tt
        full join (select distinct t1.TDate
                                ,row_number() over (partition by t1.TDate, t1.TType order by t1.TDate) rn
                    from @TableX t1
                ) td
            on(tt.TDate = td.TDate)
)
select r.TDate
        ,r.TType
        ,d.Fruit
        ,d.Vegetable
        ,d.Meat
        ,d.Bread
from DataRN d
    full join RowsRN r
        on(d.TDate = r.TDate
            and d.TType = r.TType
            and d.rn = r.rn
            )
order by r.TDate
        ,r.TType
        ,isnull(d.Fruit,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20))
        ,isnull(d.Vegetable,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20))
        ,isnull(d.Meat,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20))
        ,isnull(d.Bread,REPLICATE(CHAR(255),20))
```

---

In response to your comment, here is how you would use another `cte` to generate the full list of dates that you would need, if you havn't got a Dates reference table already (These are tremendously useful):

```
declare @MinDate date = (select min(TDate) from @TableX);
declare @MaxDate date = (select max(TDate) from @TableX);

with Dates as
(
  select @MinDate as DateValue
  union all
  select dateadd(d,1,DateValue)
  from Dates
  where DateValue < @MaxDate
)
select DateValue
from Dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Elegant, brilliant solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: My example does not contemplate the possibility that there are zero entries of some date / type combo. When I implemented this I realized that. However, it was not difficult to overcome because inserting just one row is elementary. (Find any date / type combo where there is no matching other type for that date, and insert a row with all nulls, etc.). Just an interesting sidenote about something I forgot to think about and ask.

Comment: @DaveX  Curious as to how you are doing that, as `inserting` certainly isn't the set based way.  I would use either a static, pre-built Dates reference table or generate one in the query.

Comment: @DaveX Oh and I edited my answer to show you how to do this :)

Comment: That's good info, but that's not where I was going...in my dataset above, remove the Elderberry and see what happens.

Comment: @DaveX  Ah I see what you mean.  I feel like this whole question is a problem of report formatting rather than query formatting.  If you set your tablix up with the correct row and column groupings, missing values in one type or date should't be a problem that requires RBAR checks and inserts.

Comment: You may be correct; I have two completely separate TABLIX's and that's where the problem lies. I could probably have put all the data into one table, and I know I could have done that and formatted the blank column between them so they didn't look like they correlate (because they don't; it's just two completely separate lists) the way I already am. But it bothered me on some level to do that with uncorrelated data so I took this route to see if I could learn something. And I did, thanks to you! Even if it wasn't the most efficient way.